# Grails oracle database cannot add new

Tags: grails, groovy, oracle11g

I'm working on grails 2.4.5.
I connect my project to oracle 11g.
In datasource, I add:

```
dataSource {
            pooled = true
            dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
            driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
            username = 'grails'   // YOUR USERNAME AND PASS
            password = 'grails'
            url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521:orcl'
            dbCreate = 'update'
        }
```

Then it connects and when I create new domain, new table in db creates.
However when I add new:

```
new Book(name:'The Strain').save(flush:true)
```

Then errors appear:

```
2015-07-29 17:10:30,036 [Thread-10] ERROR plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager  - Plugin [controllers:2.4.5] could not reload changes to file [C:\Users\Thuc Tran\IdeaProjects\EmailTutorial\grails-app\controllers\emailtutorial\PlaceController.groovy]: Cannot invoke method getPropertyValue() on null object
Message: Cannot invoke method getPropertyValue() on null object
   Line | Method
->> 120 | configureScaffoldingController in ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
^   105 | doCall                         in ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin$_closure3
```

Any solutions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Two things to check. See this previous [Stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973247/grails-cannot-get-property-id-on-null-object) for some ideas and try adding the appropriate code. If that does nothing please check this [JIRA entry](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSCAFFOLD-102) for a possible bug.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I post the solution for those who need it.
On oracle, create sequence, `eg: BOOK_SEQ` on my case. Make sure that on oracle, when you add new record, id will be auto increment.
Then on the domain class, `static mapping` quote, add:

```
static mapping = {
        id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'BOOKS_SEQ']
}
```

So that's all.

If answer not clear, I feel free to answer.

Thanks.